# Travis CI build failing coverity a coverity-related phase - Do I need a token?

Tags: github, printf, travis-ci, coverity

I've recently forked a project on GitHub: `notmyuser/proj` to `myuser/proj` which is configured with both TravisCI, codecov and coverity. I commented out a part of the `.travis.yml` file, like so:

```
#env:
#  global:
#    # coverity key
#    - secure: "NKZmore/base64/chars/here"
```

... since that's the original profject's token, not mine.

Well, I am able to submit builds to coverity/synopsys for analysis; but the Travis CI build fails, with the message:

```
$ export PROJECT_NAME=myuser/proj
Coverity Scan analysis selected for branch master.
Coverity Scan API access denied. Check $PROJECT_NAME and $COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN.
```

The project name is the way my project is named on GitHub. (And it's set in `.travis.yml`; before, it was `notmyuser/proj`.)

My questions:

- Why is my access being denied? Is it, like I suspect, the lack of a token?
- How do I fix things?
- Specifically, do I need a Coverity security token, and if so, how do I get it?

Note: If you need more concrete details about the project, [here it is](https://github.com/eyalroz/printf). I was just trying to make the question a little more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need your own access token.  You should be able to get one by signing up at https://scan.coverity.com/.

Disclosure: I used to work for Coverity/Synopsys.  I am not, in this post, making any recommendation for or against the use of the Coverity service.  I am linking to it only because going to the linked site is the only way to obtain the token in question.